# go runtime.newobject closure variable malloc not in heap

Tags: go, closures, runtime

code:

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func test(x, y int) func() {
            return func() {
                    x += y
            }
    }

    func main() {
            f := test(0x100, 0x200)
            f()
            fmt.Println("close")
    }
```

compile:

`go build -gcflags "-N -l" -o test main.go`

gdb:

```
           info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
    (gdb) l
    2
    3       import "fmt"
    4
    5       func test(x, y int) func() {
    6               return func() {
    7                       x += y
    8               }
    9       }
    10
    11      func main() {
    (gdb) l
    12              f := test(0x100, 0x200)
    13              f()
    14              fmt.Println("close")
    15      }
        (gdb) b 13
        Breakpoint 1 at 0x483291: file /home/devops/study/src/function/closed_function.go, line 13.
        (gdb) b 6 
        Breakpoint 2 at 0x4831cc: /home/devops/study/src/function/closed_function.go:6. (2 locations)
        (gdb) r
        Starting program: /home/devops/study/src/function/test 

        Breakpoint 2, main.test (x=256, y=512, ~r2={void ()} 0xc420043f20) at /home/devops/study/src/function/closed_function.go:6
        6               return func() {
        (gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
        (gdb) disassemble 
    Dump of assembler code for function main.test:
       0x0000000000483180 :     mov    rcx,QWORD PTR fs:0xfffffffffffffff8
       0x0000000000483189 :     cmp    rsp,QWORD PTR [rcx+0x10]
       0x000000000048318d :    jbe    0x483240 
       0x0000000000483193 :    sub    rsp,0x28
       0x0000000000483197 :    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20],rbp
       0x000000000048319c :    lea    rbp,[rsp+0x20]
       0x00000000004831a1 :    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x40],0x0
       0x00000000004831aa :    lea    rax,[rip+0x103af]        # 0x493560
       0x00000000004831b1 :    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],rax
       0x00000000004831b5 :    call   0x40e3c0 
       0x00000000004831ba :    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
       0x00000000004831bf :    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18],rax
       0x00000000004831c4 :    mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x30]
       0x00000000004831c9 :    mov    QWORD PTR [rax],rcx
    => 0x00000000004831cc :    lea    rax,[rip+0x1e44d]        # 0x4a1620
       0x00000000004831d3 :    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],rax
       0x00000000004831d7 :    call   0x40e3c0      # this wihle return a unsafe.Poniter
       0x00000000004831dc :    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
       0x00000000004831e1 :    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],rax
       0x00000000004831e6 :   lea    rcx,[rip+0x133]        # 0x483320 
       0x00000000004831ed :   mov    QWORD PTR [rax],rcx
       0x00000000004831f0 :   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
       0x00000000004831f5 :   test   BYTE PTR [rax],al
       0x00000000004831f7 :   mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [rip+0xc2de3]        # 0x545fe0 
       0x00000000004831fd :   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18]
       0x0000000000483202 :   lea    rdi,[rax+0x8]
       0x0000000000483206 :   test   ecx,ecx
       0x0000000000483208 :   jne    0x483236 
       0x000000000048320a :   jmp    0x48320c 
       0x000000000048320c :   mov    QWORD PTR [rax+0x8],rdx
       0x0000000000483210 :   jmp    0x483212 
       0x0000000000483212 :   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
       0x0000000000483217 :   test   BYTE PTR [rax],al
       0x0000000000483219 :   mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x38]
       0x000000000048321e :   mov    QWORD PTR [rax+0x10],rcx
       0x0000000000483222 :   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
       0x0000000000483227 :   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x40],rax
       0x000000000048322c :   mov    rbp,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20]
       0x0000000000483231 :   add    rsp,0x28
       0x0000000000483235 :   ret    
       0x0000000000483236 :   mov    rax,rdx
       0x0000000000483239 :   call   0x44f5c0 
       0x000000000048323e :   jmp    0x483212 
       0x0000000000483240 :   call   0x44d170 
       0x0000000000483245 :   jmp    0x483180 
    End of assembler dump.
    (gdb) c
    Continuing.

    Breakpoint 1, main.main () at /home/devops/study/src/function/closed_function.go:13
    13  
    (gdb) x/16xg $rsp 
    0xc420043f10:   0x0000000000000100      0x0000000000000200
    0xc420043f20:   0x000000c42000a060      0x000000000040423c
    0xc420043f30:   0x000000c42005a058      0x0000000000000000
    0xc420043f40:   0x000000c42000a060      0x00000000004b7465
    0xc420043f50:   0x0000000000000000      0x0000000000000000
    0xc420043f60:   0x000000c42000e1d0      0x000000c420043f78
    0xc420043f70:   0x000000c42005a058      0x000000c420043f80
    0xc420043f80:   0x0000000000427f32      0x000000c42005a000
    (gdb) x/3xg 0x000000c42000a060
    0xc42000a060:   0x0000000000483320      0x000000c420014098
    0xc42000a070:   0x0000000000000200
    (gdb) x/1xg 0x000000c420014098
    0xc420014098:   0x0000000000000100
```

By looking at the address of the memory of the variable, the final corresponding variable is found, and the memory address is not on the heap, and the runtime. newobject only assigns a pointer that appears to follow and does not continue to point to the operation?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: go  closure  Local variables are not in the heap? The variable is copied to the stack？the  runtime.newobject is a useless operation?